# Utf8 encoding issue with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encoding

I have an issue after deploying my laravel website ( that works properly in local ).
Some text are not encoded correctly, 
for example : what should be Joël is JoÃ«l

Some information :

- Not all views are affected, some variables are rendered properly in a view and broken on another view ( which make me think it's not a mysql issue )
- My json response are not working anymore ( Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded ) , which make my think it must be a mysql problem ... )
- I already tried to put this in my AppServiceProvider `\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');`
- My strftime were also not working but it can be resolved with utf8_encode function of php, which is not working with my other variables.
  For example if $c->name gives JoÃ«l , utf8_encode($c->name) also gives JoÃ«l
- In config/database.php, charset is set to utf8mb4 and collaction is set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Would you have any idea to solve my problem ?

Comment: Is your malformed text come from the DB only or also from the raw strings ? (ex: translation files)

Comment: Yes it only comes from the DB , but If I make a request in command line from the terminal ( I made select * from ... ) , the text is well encoded

Comment: Well I just noticed that my flash messages are also malformed, I think it's definitely not a DB issue

Comment: If i make "file namefile.php" on my views I get : UTF-8 Unicode text

Comment: You should get UTF-8 or US-ASCII. (`encguess` will give you better results about the encoding)

Comment: I get UTF-8 as well with encguess

Comment: How about the file with containing the flash message?

Comment: UTF-8 as well ..

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in a Service Provider AppServiceProvider and put into boot method

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
```

Generally sticking to UTF-8 keeps life simple.

Be super careful copying and pasting from anywhere else into your code - basically always go through Notepad++ and use its convert to UTF-8 (without BOM) before copying and pasting into your code.

Then make sure all your views (including error pages), have

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Or the following if you're doing HTML4

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: what is the location of Blade class? Needed for use statement like:
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager; ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution :

I use

```
{!! htmlentities($variable, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") !!}
```

But it's not convenient ...

I tried :

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(htmlentities(%s,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))');
```

in AppServiceProvider but it doesn't solve the problem.

So it's a temporary solution ...

Answer (score 0):

I just **removed charset** from **config/database.php** file. Now Its working fine for me.

```
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```