# Blade file display null for the variable that was sent

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, utf-8, laravel-blade

Consider this function:

```
    protected function displayMonitor()
    {
        $data = DisplayMonitorResource:: collection(Order:: where([
            ...
            ['mount', '>', 0]
        ])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get());
        return $data;
     }
```

The output of above function is as follows (as json in the browser):

[image]

But when I want to pass the `$data` variable to `monitor.blade.php`, non-numeric characters (Persian character) are considered `null`:

```
    protected function displayMonitor()
    {
        $data = DisplayMonitorResource:: collection(Order:: where([
            ...
            ['mount', '>', 0]
        ])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get());
        return View::make('monitor')->with('data', $data);
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739238/utf8-encoding-issue-with-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try the line below for your return view.

```
return View::make('monitor', $data);
```

Comment: `$data` variable is an `object` type, no `array`.

Comment: I think `$data` is an array containing object from the query you made. try `return view('monitor', $data);` as well.