# How to replace or encode single and right double quotation mark in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, special-characters, encode, quotes

I have string contains this `“No.”` as you see that's not normal double quotes. I tried to encode it manually by using `replace` like this

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replace('“', '\u201c');
stmt = stmt.replace('”', '\u201d');

console.log(stmt);
```

But when I log `stmt` I find that nothing changed at all and logs this `“No.”`. How can I encode such special characters in Javascript? I'm using `sequelize` to insert this statement to the database and need it to be encoded to be displayed correctly inside a JSON string so the final result should be `\u201cNo.\u201d`

Comment: Just use single quotes or backticks? `'"'` or `\`"\``, or escape it in double quotes `"\""`

Comment: You may want to reference this answer regarding encoding issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739238/utf8-encoding-issue-with-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the escape character \ to prevent JS to interpret "\u201c" and "\u201d" as unicode characters.

Check this:

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replace('“', '\\u201c');
stmt = stmt.replace('”', '\\u201d');

console.log(stmt);
```

Comment: no not yet trying to figure out the issue while inserting into MySQL

Comment: logging the result will output only 1 backslash but it got inserted with the backslash into MySQL so I had to edit it to be `replace('“', '\\\u201c')` and the other replace statement as well. Thanks a lot for your effort I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the unicode references. Just pass in the quotations as normal, within single quotes.

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replace('“', '"');
stmt = stmt.replace('”', '"');

console.log(stmt);
```

Comment: Yes, currently you are just replacing the quotes with themselves so the output remains the same.

Comment: Anyway to encode it? Laravel encodes it thus it gets displayed the same in frontend without converting it into traditional quotes

Comment: @YashSonalia, I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The incoming characters are clearly different than the ones that are being replaced.

Comment: Do you want to log this:  ```"select \u201cNo.\u201d"```

Comment: @PHPUser, I added a comment to the main question that shows a similar problem in stack overflow.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: @YashSonalia exactly I want to log this `\u201cNo.\u201d`

Comment: Okay, I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** It is better to replace all characters in a single go use regex `/“|”/g`:

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replace(/“|”/g, '"');

console.log(stmt);
```

**2)** You can also use **[replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)** here as:

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replaceAll(/“|”/g, '"');

console.log(stmt);
```

**3)** You can also replace it using its unicode value as:

```js
var stmt = "select “No.”";
stmt = stmt.replaceAll(/\u201C|\u201D/g, '"');

console.log(stmt);
```